# How to add dynamic size view above the controls?

Tags: ios, uiview

i have xib with 160 controls (UITextField ,UILabel, UIImageVIew) in scroll view. This Controls are put sequence. Now what i want is to add more controls above this 160 controls runtime in scroll view. How can i do this ??
i was trying to do like this add 1 UIView in scroll view and add dynamic controls in it and add 160 controls in other UIview in scroll view.  but the problem is when I am going to add this 160 controls in UIview there frame size are disturbed. so Is there any other solution ?? please let me know..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the `scrollView.contentSize` property to the size you want

Comment: but dynamic controls will hide my 160 static controls.

Comment: just stretch the content size and put the new controls next to the static controls